# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'selection' of undefined?

Tags: odoo, calendarview

while loading my calendar i have the error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'selection' of undefined
my view is

```
 `<record model="ir.ui.view" id="calldata_calendar_view">
               <field name="name">calldata.calendar</field>
               <field name="model">calldata</field>
               <field name="type">calendar</field>
               <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <calendar string="Call details" date_start="Call_start">
                   <field name="Dialled_number"  string="Dialled number"/>
               </calendar>
               </field>
               </record>`
```

Any one please help ?

Comment: please add more information. show your python and xml codes

Answer (score 0):

Missing color attribute in  tag.

```
<calendar string="Call details" date_start="Call_start" color="Dialled_number">
    <field name="Dialled_number"  string="Dialled number"/>
</calendar>
```

Check out more about [calendar view](http://doc.openerp.com/6.0/developer/2_6_views_events/views/calendar_view/).